# Intro QM representation of Abraham-Lorentz Force

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, radiation, hamiltonian

What does the Schrodinger equation look like if you add some term for the [Abraham-Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force)? I get a self reference term I'm not sure how to handle. I realize this is probably addressed by QED, but I like to build as much as possible from more fundamentals before heading that way. I'm also curious if I encounter meaningful concepts in such an exploration.

Let
$$\hat{H}\Psi=[(\hat{p}-q\vec{A})^2+V]\Psi=E\Psi$$
$$\hat{p}=-i\hbar\nabla$$
$$\vec{A}=\frac{\mu_0e}{4\pi r}\vec{a}$$

Various potentials, e.g.:
$$V=0,inf(r>r_0), \frac{-e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r},etc$$

The accelerations should probably be expressed as an operator, correct? Here's where I'm having trouble. 
Figure

$$\frac{-i}{\hbar}\hat{H}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$

So:

$$\hat{\vec{a}}=\frac{-i}{\hbar m}\hat{H}\hat{p}$$

$$\hat{H}\Psi=[(\hat{p}+\frac{\mu_o}{4\pi r}\frac{iq}{\hbar m}\hat{H}\hat{p})^2+V\Psi]=E\Psi$$

Can anything be done here? Perhaps a gauge transformation?

$$\vec{A'}=0, V'=V+\partial\phi/\partial t$$

$$\nabla\phi=-\vec{A}$$

Not sure if this improves things. I believe $\hat{H}\hat{p}$ appears. I don't think the vector potential can be expressed as the gradient of a potential. There is the suggestion of a third derivative of position with respect to time though which is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The Lorentz-Abraham force is an approximate way to describe the effect of internal EM interactions in a compact spatially extended charged system (usually, a charged sphere). It does not fit into the Hamiltonian formalism, hence it will be very difficult to incorporate into Schroedinger's equation in a meaningful way.

Your formulae do not make much sense. Big $A$ in the Hamiltonian

$$
H = \frac{(\mathbf p -q\mathbf A)^2}{2m}
$$
is supposed to be vector potential of *external* field (to the particle). But you write it down as a function of particle's acceleration, as if it is particle's own field. That is not how this formalism is supposed to be used. You cannot take particle's own field and put it into Hamiltonian above. It makes no physical sense, and mathematically is results in undefined expression (what is particle's field vector potential in the point where the particle is?)

Comment: I might be confused. It is considered a self force acting off of its own field, correct?

Comment: When field of a charged sphere acts on that same sphere, the net effect on the motion of the center of mass of this sphere can be described by additional force, and this is often called self-force. The EM field has finite value everywhere so its net effect can be expressed as integral over the volume of the sphere. This is not possible for point particles though.